# My MacBook died and won't start anymore

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have a 6 year old MacBook. It suddenly died last Sunday. When I started it the battery was charged to 100% - some minutes later it was at approximately 20%. Then the screen suddenly turned black and shut down.

I wasn't able to start it again since then. It usually shows the grey screen and the progress wheel but then either remains in that state for hours or turns black again.

I tried everything from [Mac OS X: Gray screen appears during startup](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2570?viewlocale=en_US): from safe boot, resetting the NVRAM/PRAM, to starting from installation disc. With the only result that it does not eject the disc anymore.

As I read, everything indicates that the hard disc is broken. Is there anything else I can do than to buy a new notebook?

Update: 
- AHT didn't inspect any problems
- boot after removing the battery didn't work

Comment: Have you checked it after removing the battery completely and connecting it to mains power? This is just to rule out any odd issues with an old battery.

Comment: Another thing to try is to boot from an external disk (if you have a clone of the internal drive or have OS X installed on an external drive) and see what happens.

Comment: Ruling out worse issues with the logic board for now, I would guess that the problem could be with the fan (broken fan or too much dust) or with the thermal paste on the CPU or the battery. You should open it, clean it once with compressed air and see what happens.

Comment: yes, tried it after removing the battery. 
and no, cannot boot from an external disc.

Comment: A failed hard drive can often prevent a Mac from booting even to an external system.  Basically when the Mac OS is loading it will automatically attempt to load any external volumes that it detects, if the internal volume is damaged/corrupted enough it will cause the good OS to hang indefinitely while attempting to mount it.  If I were you I'd remove the hard drive (remove the battery, three screws holding in the RAM shield then the hard drive pulls straight out) and try booting from an external OS again.  Even if the disk is failed you can replace just the disk, rather than the whole Mac.

Comment: Another thing to try, just to rule out bad RAM or other hardware failures, would be to run Apple Hardware Test (AHT) from one of your gray system discs.  Depending on the age of your MacBook it will either be on disc 1 (installation) or disc 2 (applications, though it should be labeled on the appropriate disc.  With the disc in your Mac you will hold down "D" while powering on, which should hopefully make it boot to AHT. More info on this can be found here http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1509?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: cool. I'll try that. Got an idea how I can remove the disc which currently is in the DVD drive. cannot eject it regularly. :-/

Comment: holding the mouse button when you turn it on should work to eject the disk. if it doesnt then you computer isnt getting far into the boot cycle at all.

Comment: @JohnSample - As Brad mentioned you should be able to eject it by holding the mouse button / trackpad button while booting.  It can take 15-30 seconds but that should do it.  IF it still doesn't eject I would boot to the Startup Manager by holding "option" while powering on, this should show all of the bootable volumes.  If you hold Eject here your optical drive should eject the disc.

Comment: AHT didn't return any issues. Does this mean the hard drive is okay?

Comment: Which model is this? Go into system information and give me the model. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to replace the internal drive.

Comment: It's a MacBook 4.1 / early 2008 and it's possibility to replace the internnal drive. But should I do that as long as I don't know if the hard drive causes the issues?

Comment: You can get an external case for the harddrive and check it with another computer. I have the exact same model, so you need to get a USB case with SATA

Answer (score 1):

so, I bought a new hard drive. installed it today and brought my MacBook back to life finally.

Did already love the idea to own a new MB Air ... maybe next year.

thx for your help guys!